# How do I find the standard deviation of the difference between two means?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I have two means and two standard deviations: M = 45.11, SD = 14.21 
M = 60.11, SD = 14.36

I know to calculate the difference in means I can take one from the other, but how do I calculate the standard deviation? Please help!!!

Edit: should have mentioned, they are dependent variables!

Comment: Assuming the variables are independent, remember that, $Var(X-Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y)$.

Comment: In that case remember that $Var(X-Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2Cov(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 4):

In order to calculate the variance of $\bar{X} - \bar{Y}$ you need to know something about the covariance between $X$ and $Y$.  If you have the original data then you can estimate the covariance directly, but absent this information we can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get an upper bound:

\begin{align}
\text{Var} \left (\bar{X} - \bar{Y} \right ) &= \sigma_x^2 / n + \sigma_y^2 / n - 2 \sigma_{\bar{x}\bar{y}} \\
&\leq \sigma_x^2 / n + \sigma_\bar{y}^2 / n + 2 | \sigma_{\bar{x}\bar{y}} | \\
&\leq \sigma_x^2 / n + \sigma_y^2 / n + 2 \sigma_x \sigma_y / n \\
&= (\sigma_x + \sigma_y)^2 / n,
\end{align}

which can be estimated by plugging in the appropriate point estimates.  This could potentially be quite a bit larger than the actual variance as it's only achieved when $X$ and $Y$ are perfectly negatively correlated, but it's the best you can do without more information.

Comment: Note that the last line could be rewritten as $(\sigma_x+\sigma_y)^2/n$, which is a useful form when you want to work out an upper bound for the standard error of the difference.

Comment: Right, let me add that to my post.